# How to properly encode url with python3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I have gone through many questions on this and still having problems encoding this, what's the proper way to urlencode this string?

Here is what I tried but it still comes with `/`

```
 import urllib.parse
 urllib.parse.quote('https://822ee.ngrok.io/?invoice_id=2323')
```

what am I missing?

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: @usr2564301: The slashes are not being encoded. So if you execute this code you get: "https%3A//82c732ee.ngrok.io/%3Finvoice_id%3D2323"

Comment: @gil.fernandes: well, that is why I get too -- no error so "working as designed" and *not* "not working". OP has to clarify what it is about that output that causes "problems", and what about it is not "the proper way" and so "not working".

Comment: @usr2564301: I agree. the question is not very clear, so I responded on the basis of what I could assume.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare the safe character as an empty string for this to deliver the right result:

```
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.quote('https://82c732ee.ngrok.io/?invoice_id=2323', safe=''))
```

This will print out:

```
https%3A%2F%2F82c732ee.ngrok.io%2F%3Finvoice_id%3D2323
```

Just out of curiosity, if you try the same thing in Java with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String s = URLEncoder.encode("https://82c732ee.ngrok.io/?invoice_id=2323", "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will print out the same result as above.

Edit:

An alternative to declaring no safe characters would be to use the `quote_plus` method, like [Nikos M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591273/nikos-m) mentioned in his comment.

Example:

```
print(urllib.parse.quote_plus('https://82c732ee.ngrok.io/?invoice_id=2323'))
```

Comment: or even use `urllib.parse.quote_plus` to quote the space as well if needed

Comment: yes this is exactly what I need, but  I get this error on importing `urllib` 
`ImportError: No module named parse`

Comment: using python 3x

Comment: @BernardParah I am using "Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda, Inc.". You can download it from here: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: thanks, I am working on a web app though(django) so I might have to find another way